# Struts2 error while executing on tomcat

Tags: java, struts

I am new in struts and I try my first program but error display starting tomcat v9.0 at local host has encountered a problem I am tried many ways to solve this problem but not solve 
My code are following also I am added all library still I get this error

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>StrutsEx1</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
  <filter-name>Controller</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>Controller</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

**Adder.java**

```
package com.test;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
public class Adder{
    int num1,num2,sum;
    public int getNum1() {
        return num1;
    }
    public void setNum1(int num1) {
        this.num1 = num1;    }
    public int getNum2() {
        return num2;
    }
    public void setNum2(int num2) {
        this.num2 = num2;    }
    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
    public void setSum(int sum) {
        this.sum = sum;    }
    public String execute(){
        sum=num1+num2;
        return "success";}}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<struts>
<package name="first" extends="struts-default">
<action name="adder" class="com.test.Sample">
<result name="success">/result.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="adder">
<s:textfield name="num1" label="first no"/>
<s:textfield name="num2" label="second no"/>
<s:submit value="Add"/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**result.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Sum is<s:property value="Sum"/></h3><hr/>
<jsp:include page="index.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying addition example but same error is getting to check server is proper or not I try simple JSP servlet example that work fine but for this example I getting error

Following error I get

```
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:StrutsEx1' did not find a matching property.
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 21 2017 09:44:18 UTC
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.0.0
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             E:\Java\jre1.8
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         E:\Shravan\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         E:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=E:\Shravan\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=E:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=E:\Shravan\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22\endorsed
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [E:\Java\jre1.8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;E:/Java/jre1.8/bin/server;E:/Java/jre1.8/bin;E:/Java/jre1.8/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;E:\eclipse;;.]
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-82"]
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8011"]
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2490 ms
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Example1]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:657)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Example1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Logger;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationFilterAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4993)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
    ... 40 more

Aug 17, 2018 8:46:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:657)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    ... 13 more

Aug 17, 2018 8:46:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:657)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)

Aug 17, 2018 8:46:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-82"]
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8011"]
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-82"]
Aug 17, 2018 8:46:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8011"]
```

Comment: In general it's helpful to actually *include the error*. And the version of Struts 2. And the `pom.xml` (and if you're doing dependency management by hand, which you shouldn't, the libraries you're deploying and how). And indent *all* of your code, consistently; much harder to read without proper indentation and whitespace.

Comment: I am using struts2 while deploy project I getting error "starting tomcat v9.0 at local host has encountered a problem" but same server work fine for other projects any suggestions

Comment: What version? What's in the logs? What's the actual error? I don't know what you expect if you don't provide anything actionable.

Comment: When I run my index.jsp I get error "tomcat v9.0 at local host has encountered a problem" so what is wrong in my code please suggest

Comment: What version *of Struts 2*? What's in the logs? What's the actual error? I don't know what you expect if you don't provide anything actionable.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Logger;` Which leads me to believe you're doing dependency management by hand. Don't do that. The error is *right there*.

Comment: Error log now I given in question and I am using struts 2.5.16 version and tomcat 9.0 please suggest me any solution

Comment: Deploy all the libraries you need.

Comment: I am already insert log4j.jar but still same error

Comment: I doubt it; there is very little ambiguity here.

Comment: I remove log4j and again insert still same error show

Comment: Is there anything wrong in web.xml and struts.xml

Comment: The app server isn't finding it--however you're doing it, it's probably wrong. web.xml and struts.xml have nothing to do with Tomcat being able to find required libraries. *How* are you "inserting" it? Are you restarting Tomcat? The error is *very* clear.

Comment: using configure build path->Add jars I am add log4j jar and also I am not print logs anywhere also I try using restart tomcat

Comment: The build path is irrelevant, it's what's put in your app's libs that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this question I am added all the jar of struts 2 so it create conflict I remove all jar and again insert jar which is required and also I make small mistake in web.xml filter name is different which is must be same